# linux mint corsair k70 keyboard not connecting for crypto setup password

Tags: linux, keyboard, linux-mint

OS: Linux mint 18.3

keyboard: corsair k70 lux

drivers: not sure, something from git.

As the title suggests, my keyboard does not work in the Linux Mint splash screen, so I wait wait for the crypto password splash screen load, turn off the computer, turn on again, linux mint uses a console looking screen for the crypt password, and the keyboard works. There are no other issues within linux, the scroll wheel and the light work.

Not sure what has changed, but I recently updated and now the restart puts me back into the splash screen, no chance to enter my password. Any suggestions?